# Domain in Many2one Odoo 11

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11, zohobooks

I have three models

```
class ZohoTags(models.Model):
    _name = 'zoho.tags'

    name = fields.Char(string="Tags")
    tag_id = fields.Char(string="Tag Id")


class TagsLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'zoho.tags.line'

    x_zoho_tags = fields.Many2one('zoho.tags', string='Tags')
    x_tags_option = fields.Many2one('zoho.tag.option', string='Tags Option', domain="[('tag_ids', '=', x_zoho_tags.tag_id)]")
    rules_id = fields.Many2one('hr.salary.rule')


class TagOptions(models.Model):
     _name = 'zoho.tag.option'

     name = fields.Char(string="tag option name")
     option_tag_id = fields.Char(string="tag option id")
     tag_ids = fields.Char(string="tag_id")
```

In the `zoho.tags` model, I have a field called `tag_id` and in the `zoho.tag.option`, I have `tag_ids` and both are having the same values.

In the `zoho.tags.line` model, I have a `Many2one` field called `x_zoho_tags`, which shows a list of tags like: `division, state, etc.` and `x_tags_option`, which shows options for each tag, such as:

> Tag (division) has options (A,B,C) and these options are having the same `tag_ids` stored for (division) tag

**I want to add a domain to `x_tags_option` in order to filter `x_tag_option` 
to show only options that are having the same `tag_id`.**

So when I select `division` from `x_zoho_tags`, then `x_tags_option` should show only `A, B and C`.

I have tried to add this line below, but it does not work

```
domain="[('tag_ids', '=', x_zoho_tags.tag_id)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out. This is how I have done it:

In python:

```
  @api.onchange('x_zoho_tags')
  def onchange_tags(self):
      res = {}
      if self.x_zoho_tags:
         res['domain'] = {'x_tags_option': [('tag_ids', '=', self.x_zoho_tags.tag_id)]}
      return res
```

In XML:

```
 <field name="x_zoho_tags"/>
 <field name="x_tags_option" onchange="onchange_tags(x_zoho_tags)"/>
```